# Git: Update branch before checking out

Tags: git

On the staging server, I have a branch checked out with the name **develop** currently with the latest code of dev changes. I merged this branch to the branch with the name master with live code in git. Now on the staging server, I want to checkout the newly updated master branch. So I do

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

This replaces with old code first and then with pull updates with new code. How can I get the latest updates in master branch first and then replace the code?
I tried

```
git fetch 
git checkout master
```

But I still get the old code and need to pull it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `git rebase origin/master`. This will *update* your current *branch* with the *changes* in the **remote master branch**.